# All Scripts Stop Working After Navigating on Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm currently working on a mobile version of a website, the desktop version is working perfectly. On mobile, after the first navigation (random internal page), all jQuery scripts stop working. Even when I navigate back to index, it doesn't execute previously working scripts.

I have included html parts, for example:

```
$(".header").load("header.html");
```

And lots of different in-page scripts or slideshows, toggle buttons.

I'm aware of the [DOM loading issue](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/), tried all solution, none of them fixed the bug.

So how can I fix this without creating a completely different mobile version of the website?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `load()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax( {
    url: "header.html",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $(".header").html(html);
      }
    });
});
```